# Add script in Magento 2.1 admin section header

Tags: magento-2.1

i need to add a JS script in the admin HEADER tag in the admin section for all pages. how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `default.xml` in your **own** module.

**Path:**

> app/code/Name_Space/Module_Name/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

And put below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <script src="module_name::js/customjsfile.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

Comment: thanks, and where to save "customjsfile.js"?

Comment: It should under `app/code/Name_Space/Module_Name/view/adminhtml/web/js` folder.

Comment: ONE PROBLEM, how to add a remote script? LOOKS like magetno alwasy try to use local scripts and add the website root URL before the src

Comment: <script src="https://www.google.com/yourscript.js" src_type="url" />

Comment: perfect. worked well